# variable selection and model selection

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I have a disease dataset, for this dataset. 
disease_rate is the dependant variable, and rest independant's.

```
data <- read.csv("H:/uni/MS_DS/disease.csv")
data

> data
         radius      texture perimeter   area smoothness desease_rate
1  -0.018743998  0.002521470 -0.005025 0.0710 0.00000000         0.07
2  -0.027940652  0.003164681 -0.004625 0.0706 0.06476967         0.02
3   0.002615946  0.001328688 -0.005525 0.0726 0.06268457         0.07
4   0.041963329  0.002769471 -0.004325 0.0699 0.06013138         0.06
5   0.030261380  0.005725780 -0.003525 0.0695 0.05942403         0.04
6  -0.030559594  0.001576348 -0.002525 0.0695 0.06110087         0.05
7   0.002698690 -0.003028856 -0.006025 0.0706 0.06207810         0.07
8  -0.044996901  0.000617110 -0.009525 0.0691 0.05940039         0.05
9   0.022993350 -0.000637109 -0.015425 0.0695 0.05870643         0.03
10  0.001398530 -0.000470057 -0.017125 0.0705 0.05540871         0.01
11  0.026827990  0.000509490 -0.014025 0.0681 0.05588225         0.06
12 -0.076220726  0.001018820 -0.010225 0.0631 0.05515852         0.01
13 -0.021917789  0.000822517 -0.003925 0.0576 0.05584590         0.03
14  0.012491060 -0.007363090  0.005175 0.0569 0.05120000         0.03
15  0.038281834 -0.008005798  0.014975 0.0576 0.04940000         0.06
16 -0.033198384  0.000350052  0.022875 0.0564 0.04930000         0.01
17 -0.002358179  0.003846831  0.022675 0.0572 0.05050000         0.07
18  0.020808766  0.000536629  0.024575 0.0656 0.04820000         0.04
19  0.091888897 -0.002393641  0.009775 0.0761 0.04740000         0.07
20 -0.036293550 -0.002889337  0.001775 0.0828 0.04770000         0.01
```

PART 1: MANUAL VARIABLE SELECTION METHOD:

```
#Multiple Linear Model - fitting the model. 
multilinearmodel = lm(desease_rate ~ radius + texture + perimeter + area +                                 
smoothness, data = df1)
summary(multilinearmodel)

Call:
lm(formula = desease_rate ~ radius + texture + perimeter + area + 
    smoothness, data = df1)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.032172 -0.013960 -0.004256  0.013622  0.033051 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.06616    0.06155   1.075   0.3006  
radius       0.33809    0.14270   2.369   0.0327 *
texture      1.16524    1.54157   0.756   0.4623  
perimeter   -0.02464    0.46819  -0.053   0.9588  
area        -0.06218    0.82411  -0.075   0.9409  
smoothness  -0.36014    0.38102  -0.945   0.3606  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0219 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3298,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.09049 
F-statistic: 1.378 on 5 and 14 DF,  p-value: 0.2909

> #Anova test.  
> anova(multilinearmodel)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: desease_rate
           Df    Sum Sq    Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
radius      1 0.0026031 0.00260313  5.4272 0.03531 *
texture     1 0.0002587 0.00025868  0.5393 0.47484  
perimeter   1 0.0000134 0.00001340  0.0279 0.86964  
area        1 0.0000012 0.00000118  0.0025 0.96109  
smoothness  1 0.0004285 0.00042853  0.8934 0.36058  
Residuals  14 0.0067151 0.00047965                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> # AIC
> AIC(multilinearmodel)
[1] -89.2251

> # BIC
> BIC(multilinearmodel)
[1] -82.25498
```

here only radius had a p value - P <= 0.05, rest all other variable has p value greater that radius.

is there any way to do the variable selection in such situation? cause rest all other variable has greater p value.

If there's any we can do for variable selection, please suggest. Also please help me to extract Mallows CP value for this model.

PART 2: 
    #Variable selection using automatic methods

```
library(leaps)
library(MASS)

model <- regsubsets(desease_rate ~  radius + texture + perimeter + area + smoothness, data = df1, nbest = 1, method = "forward",  
nvmax =4 )

summary(model)

Subset selection object
Call: regsubsets.formula(desease_rate ~ radius + texture + perimeter + 
    area + smoothness, data = df1, nbest = 1, method = "forward", 
    nvmax = 4)
5 Variables  (and intercept)
           Forced in Forced out
radius         FALSE      FALSE
texture        FALSE      FALSE
perimeter      FALSE      FALSE
area           FALSE      FALSE
smoothness     FALSE      FALSE
1 subsets of each size up to 4
Selection Algorithm: forward
         radius texture perimeter area smoothness
1  ( 1 ) "*"    " "     " "       " "  " "       
2  ( 1 ) "*"    " "     " "       " "  "*"       
3  ( 1 ) "*"    "*"     " "       " "  "*"       
4  ( 1 ) "*"    "*"     " "       "*"  "*"
```

i am not sure what should be done after this code: 
how can the variable selection process done automatically???
please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about this problem that makes 'variable selection' a good idea.  The distortions in statistical inference caused by variable selection, especially in standard errors, is large.  Use subject matter knowledge to guide the complete pre-specification of the model, and stop worrying about any effects of the model being 'insignificant'.  See my [course notes](http://fharrell.com/links) for details.

Comment: does this variable selection proceedure done automatically, please check my PART 2 - CODE,  does this makes any sense?

Comment: No, see my general comment above.  Must get the statistical principles right first.